# PFAnalytics trackEvent exc_bad_access

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm trying to use Parse analytics in my app to track errors, but when the trackEvent method is called, i receive an EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I use the code from [Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#analytics/iOS)

```
NSString *codeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [error code]];
[PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"error" dimensions:@{ @"code": codeString }];
```

I though i was doing something wrong with the dimensions NSDictionnary, so i tried:

```
[PFAnalytics trackEvent:@"error"];
```

But I'm still receiving the same signal. I know that EXC_BAD_ACCESS is thrown as a result of an illegal memory access, but in that case i'm just calling static method with a simple string as a parameter, so I don't know what i'm doing wrong.

Have you encountered the EXC_BAD_ACCESS in that case, and how did you deal with it ?

Comment: have you already run [Parse setApplicationId:clientKey:] ?

Comment: Yes Jess I do. Every other operation (save/query/...) are working propertly

Comment: what version of the Parse SDK? I'm using the latest and it's not happening for me. Have you tried a different event name - same result?

Comment: For me this was caused by parse loading the ActivityView. See if you can see the activityView in the status bar right before the crash. I had to remove Parse until I find a solution.